# ошибка создания базы данных "near \")\": syntax error Unable to execute statement"

Tags: sql, qt

Не могу понять откуда ошибка создания базы данных.

```
"near \")\": syntax error Unable to execute statement"
```

Вот вывод программы при старте :

```
nameBase : "E:/my_project/test_test_texn/DataBase.db"
nameBase : "E:/my_project/test_test_texn/DataBase.db"
DataBase: error of create  TableExample
"near \")\": syntax error Unable to execute statement"
Программа неожиданно завершилась.
Процесс был завершён принудительно.
E:/my_project/test_test_texn/release/test_test_texn.exe аварийно завершился.
```

И вот функция где она падает :

```
/* Метод для создания таблицы в базе данных
 * */
bool DataBase::createTable()
{
    /* В данном случае используется формирование сырого SQL-запроса
     * с последующим его выполнением.
     * */
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " ("
                            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            TABLE_DATE      " DATE            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_TIME      " TIME            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_RANDOM    " INTEGER         NOT NULL,"
                        " )"
                    )){
        qDebug() << "DataBase: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

при  этом раньше было так (и всё работало)

```
/* Метод для создания таблицы в базе данных
 * */
bool DataBase::createTable()
{
    /* В данном случае используется формирование сырого SQL-запроса
     * с последующим его выполнением.
     * */
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " ("
                            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            TABLE_DATE      " DATE            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_TIME      " TIME            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_RANDOM    " INTEGER         NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_MESSAGE   " VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL"
                        " )"
                    )){
        qDebug() << "DataBase: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Я удалил одну строку. Не могу понять почему произошла ошибка и как её исправить ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ой всё разобрался прочитал ошибку :3

Надо было запятую убрать, вот так :

```
/* Метод для создания таблицы в базе данных
 * */
bool DataBase::createTable()
{
    /* В данном случае используется формирование сырого SQL-запроса
     * с последующим его выполнением.
     * */
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " ("
                            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            TABLE_DATE      " DATE            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_TIME      " TIME            NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_RANDOM    " INTEGER         NOT NULL"
                        " )"
                    )){
        qDebug() << "DataBase: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]